# Get Uri from file I just created (android)

Tags: java, android, file, uri

forgive me for what is probably a stupid question, but I really can't find the answer anywhere.

I need my program to save the contents of an EditText as an html file and share it with other applications. To do this, I need to write the file to internal storage and then get the URI to it. However, there is no information anywhere (that I could fine) on how to do that.

This is my code (Editor being the name of the Activity and myapp the package):

```
String filename = "Lorem ipsum.html";

            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(Html.toHtml(textField.getText()).getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println(filename);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(Editor.this)
                        .setStream(FileProvider.getUriForFile(Editor.this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", new File(filename)))
                        .getIntent();
                shareIntent.setData(FileProvider.getUriForFile(Editor.this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", new File(filename)));
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

As far as I can tell, the file creation part works just fine; no exception is caught. However, the actual sharing part crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /Lorem ipsum.html
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong when trying to find the URI, but I've been unable to find a solution. Following the official documentation did not help and I could find no examples of this specific problem.

If it matters, here is my fileprovider declaration:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(Editor.this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", new File(filename))
```

The third parameter is equivalent to:

```
new File("Lorem ipsum.html"");
```

which is invalid.

You should use the full path of the file as the parameter in the constructor of the `File`.

As commented by @Fatih you should use

```
new File(getFilesDir(), filename)
```

as the third parameter.

Also your `authorities` parameter in manifest should be corrected as:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

So your final statement will be:

```
Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(Editor.this,
        getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
        new File(Editor.this.getFilesDir(), filename));
```

Comment: That's part of my problem though - I have no idea what the path is and how to find it

Comment: where is the file located in your phone?

Comment: I am trying to access the file I just created (with the code I posted), I don't know for sure where the app saves it.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the path where files are created? I couldn't find  instructions on that, all I can find when looking for how to save files internally are examples with just the file name.

Comment: openFileOutput() saves file to internal folder of your app. To get folder to that file you should call getFilesDir(). It should be like this  new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

Comment: I tried this, if fails with the same error, but the path is now /data/data/com.myapp/files/Lorem ipsum.html

Comment: ... And path.xml should be properly configured

Comment: Thank you, I found a mistake in the paths file. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In res/xml folder paths file change:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths><!-- NOT THIS: <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->`

In case if authorities parameter in manifest is :

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

And within the java code :

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```